# Mi petición AJAX, no devuelve respuesta

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax

Tengo un formulario en el que voy a subir una imagen, HTML5 para el formulario, JS para obtener datos y validación y PHP para el back.

Entonces, obtengo por una función todos los datos del formulario:

**HTML5**

```
<?php

require_once '../model/categoriaModel.php';
$dataForm = new CategoriaModel();

?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/design-food-menu.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  
  <main role="main" class="backblack">
    <br><br>
    <div class="container ">
      <h2 class="featurette-heading">Capturar <span class="text-muted">Nuevo Producto o Platillo.</span></h2>
      <p class="lead">Todos los campos con * son obligatorios. Captura la información de manera correcta.</p>
      <br>
      <form id="contact" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="telefono">Imagen del Producto (500px * 500px)</label>
            <img src="../assets/img/not_found.jpg" class="img_n_f" id="output">
            <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
              <a class="upload-btn text-center text-white" >Upload a file</a>

              <input type="file" name="url_img" id="url_img" style="width: 100%;" onchange="document.getElementById('output').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" />
              
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nombre">Nombre del Producto o Platillo</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_producto" placeholder="ej: Pasta Alfredo" name="nombre_producto" minlength="4" maxlength="250" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$">
              <div class="valid-feedback">Correcto.</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Ingresa un nombre de producto correcto. No aceptamos puros espacios en blanco. Min 5 Max 250 caracteres. No usar (*%/$+-.,).</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="empresa">Descripción General</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion_producto" placeholder="ej: La Pasta Alfredo consiste en una técnica de ....." name="descripcion_producto" minlength="5" maxlength="500" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$">
              <div class="valid-feedback">Correcto.</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Ingresa una descripción correcta. No aceptamos puros espacios en blanco. Min 5 Max 500 caracteres. No usar (*%/$+-.,).</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="servicio">Categoria del Producto</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="id_categoria" name="id_categoria" required>
                <option value="">Selecciona la categoria del producto...</option>
                <?php
                $dataForm->getCategoria();
                ?>
              </select>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Correcto.</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Selecciona una opción...</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tipo_descuento">Tipo de Descuento</label><br>
              <input type="radio" name="descuento" value="pesos"> desc en $ <input type="radio" name="descuento" value="porcentaje"> desc en %  <input type="radio" name="descuento" value="ninguno"> sin descuento

              <div class="valid-feedback">Correcto.</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Selecciona una opción...</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="descHide">
              <label for="desc_total">Descuento del Producto</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="number" id="desc_total" name="desc_total" pattern="[0-9]{10}" value="0" min="-9999" max="0">
              <div class="valid-feedback">Correcto.</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Ingresa un descuento correcto, no aceptamos letras, o caracteres extraños.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="telefono">Precio del Producto</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="number" id="precio_producto" name="precio_producto" placeholder="ej: 250" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Correcto.</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Ingresa un precio correcto, no aceptamos letras, o caracteres extraños.</div>
            </div>

            <a onclick="sendForm(this)" class="btn btn-success text-white shadow-lg btn-lg">Guardar</a>

          </div>
          
        </div>
      </form>
      <br><br><br>
    </div>

  </main>

  <!-- SUCCESS / FAIL ACTION MODAL -->
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="actionModal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2 class="modal-title"><p id="successModalTitle"></p></h2>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <form>
          <!-- Modal body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p id="successModalDescription"></p>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="this.form.reset();">Continuar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="text-muted bg-white">
    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <p class="float-right">
        <a href="#" class="text-warning">Volver al Principio</a>
      </p>
        <br>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="../assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/producto.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="../assets/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Y después vía Jquery obtengo los datos, valido y mando vía AJAX a PHP de la siguiente manera:

```
// Disable form submissions if there are invalid fields
function sendForm(){ 
    // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {

        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          //$('#actionModal').modal('toggle');
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();

        }else{
          var id_categoria = $("#id_categoria option:selected").val();
          var nombre_producto = $("#nombre_producto").val();
          var descripcion_producto = $("#descripcion_producto").val();
          var url_img = $('#url_img').prop('files')[0];
          //var url_img = $('#url_img')[0].files[0];
          var precio_producto = $("#precio_producto").val();
          var desc_total = $("#desc_total").val();
          var tipo_descuento = $("input[name='descuento']:checked").val();

          if(tipo_descuento=="ninguno"){
            var tipo_descuento = "0";
          }else if(tipo_descuento=="porcentaje"){
            var tipo_descuento = "1";
          }else if(tipo_descuento=="pesos"){
            var tipo_descuento = "2";
          }

            //alert('-> ' + id_categoria + ', ' + nombre_producto + ', ' + url_img + ', ' +tipo_descuento + ', ' + descripcion_producto );

          var formData = new FormData();

          formData.append('id_categoria',id_categoria);
          formData.append('nombre_producto',nombre_producto);
          formData.append('descripcion_producto',descripcion_producto);
          formData.append('archivo',url_img);
          formData.append('precio_producto',precio_producto);
          formData.append('desc_total',desc_total);
          formData.append('tipo_descuento',tipo_descuento);
          formData.append('function',"addDataForm");

          $.ajax({
              data:  formData, //send data via AJAX
              url:   '../controller/ctrlProducto.php', //url file controller PHP
              dataType:'json',
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              type:  'post', //send POST data
              success:function(response) { //get request
                
              if(response.success){ 
                $("#successModalTitle").html("<i class='fas fa-check-circle color-success'></i> ¡Éxito!");
                $("#successModalDescription").html(response.message);
                $("#contact").trigger("reset");
                $("#contact").removeClass("was-validated");
              }else{
                $("#successModalTitle").html("<i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle color-error'></i> ¡Error!");
                $("#successModalDescription").html(response.message);
              }
                
                $('#actionModal').modal('toggle');      
              }
          });

        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
    });

}
```

y ya en PHP, hago lo siguiente, que es realmente, insertar datos, guardar la imagen y el PHP devuelve un JSON con 2 atributos a mi petición AJAX, para que yo lo lea en JS y le asigne un mensaje de ÉXITO a mi MODAL y lo muestre.

```
$nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
                //$ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
        $url_imagen = "../assets/img/productos/" . $nombre;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $url_imagen)) {
            print_r("El Archivo ha sido subido correctamente.");    
        } else {
            print_r("Lo sentimos, hubo un error subiendo el archivo.");
        }
    
        require_once 'conn/connection.php';
        $connect = new connection();
        $connection=$connect->connections();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO producto (id_categoria, nombre_producto, descripcion_producto, url_imagen, precio_producto, desc_total, tipo_descuento, f_creacion, f_actualizacion, status) VALUES ('".$_POST['id_categoria'] ."','".$_POST['nombre_producto']."','".$_POST['descripcion_producto']."','".$nombre."','".$_POST['precio_producto']."','".$_POST['desc_total']."','".$_POST['tipo_descuento']."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."', '1');";

        //print_r($sql);
        $jsondata = array();

        if ($connection->query($sql)===true) {
            $message= "Tu información ha sido enviada correctamente.";
            $jsondata['success'] = true;
            $jsondata['message'] = $message;

        } else {
            $message= "Hemos tenido un problema al guardar un información, contacta al servicio técnico.";
            $jsondata['success'] = false;
            $jsondata['message'] = $message;
        }
                //Aunque el content-type no sea un problema en la mayoría de casos, es recomendable especificarlo
        header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

        echo json_encode($jsondata, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

El código INSERTA bien, guarda la imagen bien, PERO NO DEVUELVE LA REPUESTA, en consola veo la respuesta, pero, el MODAL nunca se activa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes un par de `print_r()` al mover el archivo y eso hace que la respuesta AJAX no sea un JSON válido.

Comment: Hermano ponlo como respuesta, me quieres explicar un poco o dame un enlace para leer más acerca de esto, por favor, me demore mucho tiempo ya en esto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La petición AJAX espera una respuesta de tipo JSON, pero con esta porción de código haces que se "rompa" el tipo:

```
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
            //$ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $url_imagen = "../assets/img/productos/" . $nombre;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $url_imagen)) {
        print_r("El Archivo ha sido subido correctamente.");    
    } else {
        print_r("Lo sentimos, hubo un error subiendo el archivo.");
    }
```

Solución: No imprimas esos mensajes.

```
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
            //$ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $url_imagen = "../assets/img/productos/" . $nombre;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $url_imagen)) {
        // Este mensaje no es necesario, coméntalo o quítalo
        // print_r("El Archivo ha sido subido correctamente.");    
    } else {
        // Hubo error, no deberías continuar... o sí?
        $jsondata[
           'success' => false,
           'message' => 'Lo sentimos, hubo un error subiendo el archivo.'
        ];
        // Fin del script con una respueta JSON válida
        die(json_encode($jsondata));
    }
```

Comment: Gracias hoy aprendi algo nuevo, al menos para mi.

Answer (score 3):

Según veo tienes unos print_r en tu mensajería de estados, al hacer un print_r interrumpes la salida de la petición AJAX JSON

```
<?php 

$nombre     = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$url_imagen = "../assets/img/productos/" . $nombre;

$success = false;
$message = '';

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $url_imagen)) {
    $success = true;
    $message = "El Archivo ha sido subido correctamente";    
} else {
    $message = "Lo sentimos, hubo un error subiendo el archivo.";
}

if($success){

    require_once 'conn/connection.php';
    $connect    = new connection();
    $connection = $connect->connections();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO producto (id_categoria, nombre_producto, descripcion_producto, url_imagen, precio_producto, desc_total, tipo_descuento, f_creacion, f_actualizacion, status) VALUES ('".$_POST['id_categoria'] ."','".$_POST['nombre_producto']."','".$_POST['descripcion_producto']."','".$nombre."','".$_POST['precio_producto']."','".$_POST['desc_total']."','".$_POST['tipo_descuento']."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."', '1');";

    if ($connection->query($sql) === true) {
    
        $message  = "Tu información ha sido enviada correctamente.";
        $success  = true;

    } else {

        $message = "Hemos tenido un problema al guardar un información, contacta al servicio técnico.";
        $success = false;
    
    }

}


$jsondata = array(
    'success'   => $success,
    'message'   => $message
);

//Aunque el content-type no sea un problema en la mayoría de casos, es recomendable especificarlo
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

echo json_encode($jsondata, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

Espero ayudarte, saludos!

Comment: te ganaron amigo, pero gracias de todos modos.